# Content type form in infopath for Content type created in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, content-type, sharepoint-2013, infopath2010

I have created content type in Visual Studio and I have to apply infopath form to that content type in infopath. How do i proceed further ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  Can you try elaborating a bit more?

Comment: I have created one content type in Visual studio and deployed this to site then what i have to do is, i have to add form to that content content type in infopath so that whereever i apply that content type to any list, then that form should appear. Can i do this by "Update existing site content type" in infopath ? or any other process should be there?